# What to import for @androidx.annotation.Nullable?

Tags: android

Doing task from Advanced Android Development Course. I have `DialView` that extends `android.view.View`. Constructors have a `@android.annotation.Nullable` parameter that blinks red. Importing `android.support.annotation.Nullable` doesn't solve the problem.

minSdkVersion is set to 15.

Error: cannot find symbol class Nullable

```
public DialView(Context context, @androidx.annotation.Nullable @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Module:app

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: which support library you're using?

Comment: It is version 20.0.0

Comment: please share your **module.gradle** code (dependency section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it was posted quite a while ago but just sharing what I found during googling.

I tried migrating to AndroidX (Go to refactor menu and Migrate to AndroidX) and was able to find the library. Similar answers and more detailed explanation are found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722247/5440297

Comment: I missed or there was no notification there is an answer.