# Cannot resolve symbol nullable

Tags: android

Getting cannot resolve symbol nullable error for my program.
@androidx.annotations.Nullable - nullable has redline under it.

```
package com.singularity.birdjumper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GameActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@androidx.annotation.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an import for nullable, i.e, `import android.support.annotation.Nullable`

Answer (score 9):

just add this import statement

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

For androidx, the import statement should be:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the AndroidX library?
It would be worth adding them into the app gradle file,

```
//set the version to latest version
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

There is also a great answer over here for more information on AndroidX and migrating your projects over to it.

[Android Studio adds both @androidx.annotation and @android.support.annotation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497475/android-studio-adds-both-androidx-annotation-and-android-support-annotation-pr)

Answer (score 1):

i hava the same problem,
sync project with gradle files or update gradle plug